# Testing devise invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I am using devise invitable in my app. I have overwritten the devise invitable invitations controller for some custom behavior. When I try and write controller tests for this I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass
```

That happens when doing `get :new`.

The route is setup as directed in the setup directions:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', invitations: 'users/invitations', registrations: :registrations }
```

The controller is under /app/controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb and name spaced correctly within the file `Users::InvitationsController` same with the test /tests/controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb `Users::InvitationsControllerTest`

This is the test:

```
context '#new' do
  context 'while not signed in' do
    should 'redirect to the login page' do
      get :new
      assert_redirected_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

This is the action:

```
def new
  self.resource = resource_class.new
  self.resource.build_group if current_inviter.is_admin?
  self.resource.group = current_inviter.group if current_inviter.is_manager?
  render :new
end
```

Appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: Can you share `new` action of InvitationsController

Comment: Also, share the failing test example in your question.

Comment: Can you share the `/app/controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb ` which you have defined?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to set Devise.mappings before every request(or in setup block) as follows -

`@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]`

This is to help devise map the routes correctly in the tests.

More info can be found here - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)